# Unsupported get request in Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

For some reason my https://graph.facebook.com/210155825774263 returns an error :

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request.",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

I tried other pages and IDs and it returns relevant (success) information.
At first I thought this was a code related error - only now I found out that this is a FB error. Is there a way to fix this inorder to get the page information in JSON format ?

Comment: What does this ID represent?

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/popsplat.in

Comment: possible duplicate of [Graph API returns 'false' or 'Unsupported get request' accessing public Facebook Page](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6843796/graph-api-returns-false-or-unsupported-get-request-accessing-public-facebook)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> This error occur due to several problem in permissions of your page
>
> **1. go to edit page ->manage permission**
>
> check Age restrictions : 13+
>
> **2. go to basic information -> Start Type::
>       set to launched**

Comment: I was able to access the graph object for an age-restricted page by supplying my auth_token in the request. Since I am over 13 I was able to get the graph object.

Comment: please post full answer, I mean where do find edit page option.

Answer (score 7):

I had also encountered this problem, and it was because the Facebook page I was managing had "County Restrictions" set in the *Manage Permissions* menu. Once I removed this restriction, the graph error went away.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem because i forgot to disable the sandbox mode. To disable it goto 
Settings->Basics->Sandbox Mode

Comment: I am getting unsupported request in my android app for the test user and not a tester I am getting app not setup error. If I disable the Sandbox mode, does it work or not?

Answer (score 1):

The page you are having trouble with is not accessible without user access token or has some or the other restrictions which are resolved only when a user logs in.

Comment: Thats not true for public info on pages. Take for example : http://graph.facebook.com/style

Comment: This page is accessible publicly, what I meant in my answer is that the page might have some restriction due to which it is accessible only with a valid access token. As I tried popsplat.in with App access token and got same error, tried opening facebook.com/popsplat.in and was redirected to Facebook's homepage to login. Using valid user access toke returned values similar to the requirement of logging in before we view page at www.facebook.com/popsplat.in

Answer (score 1):

For me adding &limit=8 in the url solve the problem, I think there were just too much information to send, and this limitation seems to be only in dev mode.
Of course for me it is 8 but for you it can be limit=1

https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/{{pageId}}/feed?access_token={{your token}}pretty=1&fields=reactions.type\u002528LIKE\u002529.limit\u0025280\u002529.summary\u0025281\u002529.as\u002528like\u002529\u00252Creactions.type\u002528LOVE\u002529.limit\u0025280\u002529.summary\u0025281\u002529.as\u002528love\u002529\u00252Creactions.type\u002528WOW\u002529.limit\u0025280\u002529.summary\u0025281\u002529.as\u002528wow\u002529\u00252Creactions.type\u002528HAHA\u002529.limit\u0025280\u002529.summary\u0025281\u002529.as\u002528haha\u002529\u00252Creactions.type\u002528SAD\u002529.limit\u0025280\u002529.summary\u0025281\u002529.as\u002528sad\u002529\u00252Creactions.type\u002528ANGRY\u002529.limit\u0025280\u002529.summary\u0025281\u002529.as\u002528angry\u002529\u00252Cfrom\u00252Ccomments.limit\u00252810\u002529.summary\u002528true\u002529\u00252Cmessage\u00252Cstatus_type\u00252Cobject_attachment\u00252Cmessage_tags\u00252Cpermalink_url\u00252C+attachments\u00257Btitle\u00252Cdescription\u00252Cmedia_type\u00252Cunshimmed_url\u00252Ctarget\u00257Bid\u00257D\u00257D&limit=8

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1.admin panel click onEdit page(at the top right of the window) select edit setting

```
check Age restrictions : select 'Anyone (13+)'

 save change( as you can see in image)
```