# Can't get public Facebook status with the API graph

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, public

My problem is simple. I want to be able to see this post with the graph:

http://www.facebook.com/midou.london.12/posts/125781047549534

This post is public so i type:

```
graph.facebook.com/IDProfile_IDPost?access_token=USER_TOKEN ( i try with the app token too)


https://graph.facebook.com/100003529196134_125781047549534?access_token=USER_TOKEN
```

but i get "message":

```
 "Unsupported get request."
```

I dont get it, i can get every posts from any public profile except status with only text, that doesnt work.

Comment: what is the first number in your request?

Comment: You should check out this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739609/unsupported-get-request-in-facebook-graph-api

Comment: @pendo it's midou.london's ID

Comment: @Cormac Driver not the same issue, the guy didnt have an access token

Comment: When I query the FB Graph with just the ID of the post (without the UserID_ prefix) I get a response that no auth token is found. What happens if you leave the userid away and just query the postid?

Comment: @PENDO

https://graph.facebook.com/125781047549534?access_token=AAAGcxJk2NgMBAGkIJQ6bE1u3GeRMLUsK1dU8cfZAHEmnTsJt4hPWo87rflfp8saaCuljp0Kb4wcVkpBEIq9tMMdylpV1QD2pv3taCugZDZD

same problem i tried, i show you the token i m using (its not important)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739609/unsupported-get-request-in-facebook-graph-api this might be a lead? What's your age?

Answer (score 1):

You can read posts of immediate friends through GRAPH API .
for a random profile (not in friends list),the graph API returns an empty JSON.

Although there is a separate API [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed ] which clearly says "Access to the Public Feed API is restricted to a limited set of media publishers and usage requires prior approval by Facebook. You cannot apply to use the API at this time.".