# Facebook Page album not accessible for some users

Tags: facebook

I have a Facebook page (id: 134536769931125)
There are multiple applications create Albums for the page and upload Photos on the fly.
It works normal for all of them except one.

When I am using my developer account I can view all of the albums and the photos. But when I am using another account (also a FB developer but not the developer of the app and not the admin of the page) I can see only two of the generated albums and can't see the last one.

The albums have been created with the same script and uploads photos using the same script, only with different album settings.

I also tried to explore for the albums using the Graph API Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) all albums are listed for the first user only when an access token with 'user_photos' permission is used. And that album is not listed for the other user at all.

However the privacy of the album is set to "everyone". And there are no different settings compared to the working ones. I assume all albums should be publicly available.

You can also try to view the data from the Graph API Explorer. Below are the Album IDs
531022926949172 (working)
425250747526391 (working)
539720712746060 (not working)

Has there been a change/bug on the Facebook side that causes this behavior?

Any reply is welcome.
And thank you reading such a long post, but I could not find a shorter way to describe in details :)

All the best,
Doruk

Comment: Are those albums all created by the same app, or different ones? If it not working for only one app, check the app settings for sandbox mode and restrictions of any kind.

Comment: try the `friend_photos` permission as well and see if that helps..

Comment: @CBroe They are different applications using the copy of the same script. The only difference is "July 2013 Breaking Changes". In the working one it is disabled, and the not working one it is enabled.

Comment: Update: To go on with the project I created the album manually from the Facebook. And then tell me application to upload to that new album. The photos that are manually uploaded are seen but the ones that are uploaded via the app does not show.

Comment: That’s interesting, because I see nothing in the roadmap that should have any effect here (the only thing vaguely related is _“Photos will no longer return larger sizes than the uploaded version”_, but that should not be the problem here).

Comment: @CBore: I also see nothing in the road map. But that does not mean FB does not change things ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The error I received was as follows:
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request.", 
    "type": "GraphMethodException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}

I found that someone else had this problem over at [Unsupported get request in Facebook Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739609/unsupported-get-request-in-facebook-graph-api) . See if the accepted answer works, and let me know..

Comment: I'm also having this problem with other people's pages. I can list the albums, but as soon as I request "photos" from the broken albums, the entire list turns to be "unsupported get request". When a request is about an individual album, I can get basic data about these albums, but again no photos. I got these permissions: user_photos, user_posts, user_videos, pages_show_list, pages_manage_metadata, pages_read_engagement, and now trying as an extra pages_read_user_content. It's in dev mode but set up by the 3rd party who wants to access his/her page.