# facebook graph api explorer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am facing a problem with Graph API Explorer, and I need to know if it's a known bug in the graph itself or whether something else is wrong.

When I try to get the posts of a page in the graph explorer, most of them show up but some do not although the post itself exists and I can access it in facebook itself.

For your better understanding of the problem here is an example-

`593482174003200_649686581716092` gives me this-

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request.", 
    "type": "GraphMethodException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

While this http://www.facebook.com/593482174003200/posts/649686581716092/  shows me the actual post.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To get all the posts of the page with id 593482174003200, enter this into the graph api explorer: 593482174003200/posts. There you see a list of posts, with clickable links in exactly the format you provided, but the post 649686581716092 doesn't show up. Have you tried with a valid access token?

Comment: the error has usually something to do with permissions, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739609/unsupported-get-request-in-facebook-graph-api

Comment: thanks for your response.

@mb21 yes i have tested it in a valid token, still the same problem.

and i checked with the page manager, there are no restrictions.