# Graph API Exception for a valid page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

Why does https://graph.facebook.com/weddingsutra doesn't work though the page https://www.facebook.com/weddingsutra is valid?

Response I am getting is

```
{
 error: {
   message: "Unsupported get request.",
   type: "GraphMethodException",
   code: 100
 }
}
```

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/weddingsutra?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

Have you tried using a valid access token?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unsupported get request in Facebook Graph API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739609/unsupported-get-request-in-facebook-graph-api)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the Age Restrictions related to your page.

You can go to **Settings -> Age Restrictions** and make sure it is accessible by anyone with an age 13+.

It should also work in case of any age restriction (example 18+), if you are supplying an Authentication Token (provided that you're 18+ in age).

Answer (score 0):

You need an access token to access information via the Graph API. You can easily generate an access token using the [graph explorer tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and then try the url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/weddingsutra?access_token={access_token}
```