# How to get information from page facebook api graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have two examples:

Example 1: 
         https://www.facebook.com/cocacola

```
     I get "likes","description" at https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/

     It work.
```

Example 2: 
         https://www.facebook.com/selectivefitness
         I get errors at https://graph.facebook.com/selectivefitness/

Why example 2 does not working? How i can get "likes" "description" of https://www.facebook.com/selectivefitness

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739609/unsupported-get-request-in-facebook-graph-api

Comment: possible duplicate of [Graph API returns 'false' or 'Unsupported get request' accessing public Facebook Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843796/graph-api-returns-false-or-unsupported-get-request-accessing-public-facebook)

Answer (score 1):

It's because of restrictions on the page (either country restrictions or age restriction). You just need a valid [Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) to fix it.

Try making a request to the URL using that Access Token. Something like:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/selectivefitness?access_token={Access_Token}
```

You can always make use of [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=selectivefitness%3Ffields%3Dlikes%2Cdescription) to test your requests and queries.