# Facebook Unity SDK for android: Unsupported get request error

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine

I am writing an app using Unity and want to share some message in the App by using facebook api. The code is pretty straightforwards:

```
FB.Init();
...
FB.ShareLink(
      new Uri("https://www.example.com"),
      "Checkout my awesome score!",
      "I reached level 100!",
      null,
      callback);
```

But get this error message:

```
  com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: [code] 100 [message]: 
    Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at 
    https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api [extra]: 
     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.a(seek time = %s:153)
     ...
```

Found this link: [Unsupported get request in Facebook Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739609/unsupported-get-request-in-facebook-graph-api). I fixed all the restrictions, but still it's not working. One caveat is that the app is not launched in Play store, it does complain when I set up the app in FB developer console:

```
    There was a problem verifying the package name com.xxx.xx on Google Play. 
    Please check the package name and try again.
    If your app isn't listed publicly on Google Play yet you can ignore this message.
```

Not sure if that could be the reason?

Comment: You are aware that you are not allowed to prefill the message

Comment: Is that so? Then how do you use that API to share the message? It's not mentioned in the doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.ShareLink

Comment: You can share messages that the user typed. You can't share messages that you wrote

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Tried to remove the prefill message, still not working (same error). I just want to share some scores of a mobile game, what api would you recommend to use? Tried FB.AppRequest as well but that seems not working for debug/test mode.

Comment: Share a link or use the scores API

Comment: Just figured out why, I need to add my tester account in the "Role" for this app which is still in development phase. Share links works now. Thanks for helping.